# How to set target in cross entropy loss for pytorch multi-class problem

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor, loss-function

**Problem Statement**: I have an image and a pixel of the image can belong to only(either) one of `Band5','Band6', 'Band7'` (see below for details). Hence, I have a pytorch multi-class problem but I am unable to understand how to set the targets which needs to be in form `[batch, w, h]`

My dataloader return two values:

```
x = chips.loc[:, :, :, self.input_bands]     
y = chips.loc[:, :, :, self.output_bands]        
x = x.transpose('chip','channel','x','y')
y_ohe = y.transpose('chip','channel','x','y')
```

Also, I have defined:

```
input_bands = ['Band1','Band2', 'Band3', 'Band3', 'Band4']  # input classes
output_bands = ['Band5','Band6', 'Band7'] #target classes

model = ModelName(num_classes = 3, depth=default_depth, in_channels=5, merge_mode='concat').to(device)
loss_new = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

In my training function:

```
        #get values from dataloader
        X = normalize_zero_to_one(X) #input
        y = normalize_zero_to_one(y) #target

        images = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X)).to(device) # [batch, channel, H, W]
        masks = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y)).to(device) 
        optim.zero_grad()        
        outputs = model(images) 

        loss = loss_new(outputs, masks) # (preds, target)
        loss.backward()         
        optim.step() # Update weights
```

I know the the target (here `masks`) should be `[batch_size, w, h]`. However, it is currently `[batch_size, channels, w, h]`.

I read a lot of posts including [1](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/bceloss-for-multiclass-problem/36675), [2](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/for-crossentropy-loss-function-why-output-and-target-size-cannot-be-the-same/46026) and they say `the target should only contain the target class indices`. I don't understand how can I concatenate indices of three classes and still set target as `[batch_size, w, h]`.

Right now, I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of dimension: 4
```

To the best of my understanding, I don't need to do any one hot encoding. Similar errors and explanation I found on the internet are here:'

- [Reference 1](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/only-batches-of-spatial-targets-supported-non-empty-3d-tensors-but-got-targets-of-size-1-1-256-256/49134)
- [Reference 2](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/unable-to-understand-the-runtime-error/19906)
- [Reference 3](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/nll-loss-error-only-batches-of-spatial-targets-supported-but-got-targets-of-dimension-1/57047)
- [Reference 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896412/channel-wise-crossentropyloss-for-image-segmentation-in-pytorch)

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your current "target" is `[batch_size, channels, w, h]` with `channels==3` as you have three possible targets.
What are the *values* in your target represent? You basically have a 3-vector target for each pixel - are these the expected class probabilities? Are they "one-hot-vectors" indicating the correct "band"?
If so, you can get the target indices by simply taking the [`argmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/torch.html#torch.argmax) along the target channel dimension:

```py
proper_target = torch.argmax(masks, dim=1)  # make sure keepdim=False
loss = loss_new(outputs, proper_target)
```